# Consola en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

No entiendo como utilizar la consola al utilizar el framework de laravel, en unas partes dice que es el tinker pero no lo se usar, he intentado con el shell de xampp pero tampoco doy con lo que busco que es crear la base de datos.

Comment: Tinker es para interactuar con la base de datos a través del query builder y/o de los modelos en tu sistema; todo esto desde una línea de comandos

Comment: Para crear tu base de datos sería mejor crearla o desde phpmyadmin o desde la consola de tu servidor

Comment: Vamos Laravel no es necesario para crear la base de datos, lo que puedes hacer es que una vez que creaste la base de datos la conectes con Laravel desde el archivo .env

Comment: Lo que creas desde Laravel hacia tu base de datos, son las tablas que la van a componer a través de las migraciones

Comment: pues, gracias por enseñarme como redactar la pregunta Shaz...

Comment: he encontrado que para trabajar en el codigo desde la consola me pongo sobre la carpeta del proyecto, sin embargo Crtl+Shift+C desde VisualCode abre la consola del proyecto, he practicado desde alli, ademas he visto como la consola y los comando de iOs son bastante diferentes por ejemplo al montar el laravel en iOs de utiliza curl..

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente estás utilizando XAMPP, por lo que debes hacer lo siguiente. Activa los servicios (apache, php, mysql, etc) y dirigete a (en el navegador):

```php
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

Ahí accederás a la interfaz de [PhpMyAdmin](https://es.slideshare.net/LeccionesWeb/phpmyadmin-con-xampp). Para iniciar sesión, accede con las credenciales por defecto (usuario: `root`, sin contraseña).

Ahí puedes crear tu base de datos, la interfaz es intuitiva.

Luego de esto tienes que decirle a Laravel que esa [base de datos](https://docs.laraveles.com/docs/5.5/database) es la que tiene que utilizar, para esto dirígete a tus variables de entorno `.env`:

> estoy asumiendo que ya has instalado Laravel exitósamente

**.env**

```php
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=el_nombre_de_tu_base_de_datos   // <---
DB_USERNAME=root   // <---
DB_PASSWORD=   // <---
```

Luego de esto, corre en consola:

```php
php artisan config:clear
```

Entonces ya podrás acceder a [Tinker](https://styde.net/tinker-consola-de-comandos-en-laravel/) a través del CLI de Laravel. [Tinker](https://styde.net/tinker-consola-de-comandos-en-laravel/) es muy útil para ejecutar sentencias de Laravel sin necesidad de montar todo el servidor:

```php
php artisan tinker
```

[image: Muestra de Laravel Tinker]

Entonces con tu base de datos ya configurada, ya puedes crear tus [migraciones](https://laraveles.com/migraciones-en-laravel/), [modelos](https://docs.laraveles.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) y todo lo demás para que armes tu sistema.

Comment: olle, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, he podido entender del tema gracias